# Parse Decimal to Integer in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is there any way to parse decimal number to integer in JSTL, if it contains zero after decimal.

`For example I want to parse 56.00 => 56 but 56.23 should remain 56.23`

I tried `fmt:parseNumber` but it parse all type of decimal number.

Comment: parsing consists in transforming a string into a number. It seems that what you want is to **format** a number, i.e. transform a number to a string.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. `fmt:formatNumber` worked for me.

`<fmt:formatNumber type="number"  groupingUsed="false" value="152.00" />`